# dictionary values in python adding values

Tags: python

So here is my problem, i have a dictionary with following key => values:

```
6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002:политичка -> 2
6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002:државата -> 2
6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002:енергично -> 1
1caa60ebf9459d9cd406f1a03e1719b675dcfaad78292edc7e4a56be:полициска -> 1
```

I have this code to show the keys needed:

```
for key, value in count_db.iteritems():
        print key[:56]
```

So now i have:

```
6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002 -> 2
6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002 -> 2
6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002 -> 1
1caa60ebf9459d9cd406f1a03e1719b675dcfaad78292edc7e4a56be -> 1
```

I need to merge them into:

```
6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002 -> 5
1caa60ebf9459d9cd406f1a03e1719b675dcfaad78292edc7e4a56be -> 1
```

I have made this but i have not succeed in doing it correctly:

```
length_dic=len(count_db.keys())
for key, value in count_db.iteritems():
    count_element=key[:56]
    #print "%s => %s" % (key[:56], value) #value[:56]

    for i in range(length_dic):
        i+=1
        if count_element == key[:56]:
            itr+=int(value) 
        print i
    length_dic=length_dic-1
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object (in version 2.7+) is for:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter()

for key, value in count_db.iteritems():
    c[key[:56]] += value
```

Comment: ValueError: too many values to unpack when i want to print it

Answer (score 4):

A trivial approach would be:

```
result = {}
for key, value in count_db.iteritems():
    result[key[:56]] = result.get(key[:56], 0) + value
```

You could also achieve the same with `reduce` if you want to get it on one line:

```
import collections
result = reduce(lambda x,y: x[y[0][:56]] += y[1] , count_db.iteritems(), collections.defaultdict(int))
```

Comment: @DameJovanoski Every time you need to do some conversion or transformation on a dict or a list, there is usually a one-line solution, even though it might not look pretty ;)

Comment: When i try to print the list i get ValueError: too many values to unpack Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Given your dictionary as

```
>>> spam={"6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002:AAAA": 2,
"6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002:BBBB": 2,
"6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002:CCCC": 1,
"1caa60ebf9459d9cd406f1a03e1719b675dcfaad78292edc7e4a56be:DDDD": 1
}
```

you can somewhat do like the following

```
>>> bacon=collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> for k,v in [(k[:56],v) for k,v in spam.iteritems()]:
    bacon[k]+=v


>>> bacon
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'6bc51fb21fd9eefef4ec97a241733cd59b71e8e14ad70e9068d32002': 5, '1caa60ebf9459d9cd406f1a03e1719b675dcfaad78292edc7e4a56be': 1})
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you did all that in your code. I think this would do the job:

```
tmp_dict = {}
for key, value in count_db.iteritems():
    count_element=key[:56]

    if count_element in tmp_dict:
        tmp_dict[count_element] += value
    else:
        tmp_dict[count_element] = value
```